# WPF - how to insert image into 2nd column of Grid element

Tags: wpf

As the subject says I want to insert an image into the 2nd column of grid
defined with 2 columndefintions.

Programmatically that is???

I cannot see how to select the column using grid.Children.insert(1, img)
does not work.

Malcolm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Image imgControl = new Image();
Grid.SetColumn(imgControl, 1);
gridContainer.Children.Add(imgControl);
```

Objects contained in a grid are positioned based on the attached dependency properties Column Row ColumnSpan and RowSpan which are set as shown above.

Comment: Shouldn't you first add the Image to the Grid and then set the column?

Comment: Either way is fine since Column is an AttachedProperty on Grid. You can set that before adding to grid.

Answer (score 5):

The row/column index on an element in WPF is an attached property. You set it using a static method on Grid, like this:

```
Grid.SetColumn(img, 1);
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumn.aspx), and more about attached properties [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).